# NO REVERT option effect of the EXECUTE AS statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand `NO REVERT` option effect of the `EXECUTE AS` statement. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) says:

> When the EXECUTE AS statement includes the optional WITH NO REVERT
>   clause, the execution context of a session cannot be reset using
>   REVERT or by executing another EXECUTE AS statement.

As I understand there are two limitations:

> session cannot be reset using REVERT

and

> session cannot be reset by executing another EXECUTE AS statement

Ok, I have two database users. One of them can impersonate the other:

```
CREATE USER U1 WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER U2 WITHOUT LOGIN;
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::U2 TO U1;
```

The first limitation is clear and work according to expectation:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'U1' WITH NO REVERT;
REVERT; --> ERROR: Msg 15196 The current security context is non-revertible.
```

With the second limitation meant, I expected that the following commands sequence

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'U1' WITH NO REVERT;
EXECUTE AS USER = 'U2'; --> OK
```

will fail once the the second `EXECUTE AS` is reached. However, it didn't failed.

So, the question is what does the second limitation meant in the documentation exactly mean? May be I understand it incorrectly or check it inappropriately.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the documentation. The syntax is not `WITH NO REVERT AND NO FURTHER EXECUTE AS`. Why would you use `WITH NO REVERT`? Is this just academic? I would suggest posting documentation feedback at the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's academic at this moment, but with intention to apply knowledge while building application security later. I agree that syntax do not promises more than it declares, however cited part of the documentation is a bit misleading. I posted feedback in the popup at the bottom of documentation, as you suggested.